# Excel formulas that disappear

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I'm new to python. I would like to process excel data with python.  I made the code below. The code works the first time I launch it. It detects all the data present in the excel file even the formulas.
The problem is that it does not work a second time. This means that a column of data is missing. It's the column where there are formulas. I would like my code to work all the time.
I noticed that it no longer detects formulas the second time I run all my code. My code interprets the formulas as'NaN' and when reading my data I ask not to display the'NaN'. That's why there's nothing.
The second remark is: if I save my excel file after launching my code for the first time, my code works again.
I would like my code to work all the time.
My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile

data=pd.read_excel("site.xlsx","Feuille1", keep_default_na=False, skiprows = [0,1],usecols=[1,2,3,4]) 
print(data)

totalballon=[]
b=[]
espece=np.where(data['Unnamed: 1']=='TOTAL Espèces')[0]
carte=np.where(data['Unnamed: 1']=='TOTAL CB')[0]
cheque=np.where(data['Unnamed: 1']=='TOTAL Chèque')[0]

articles=["Ballon bleu", "CH24 jaune", "Ballon rouge", "Chapeau", "Ballon vert", "Pantalon", "Fleurs"]

print(np.sum(data['Unnamed: 3'][espece]))
print(np.sum(data['Unnamed: 3'][carte]))
print(np.sum(data['Unnamed: 3'][cheque]))


for i in articles:
    nb=np.where(data['Unnamed: 1']==i)[0]
    b.append(np.sum(data['Unnamed: 0'][nb]))
print(b)

ballon=["Ballon bleu", "Ballon rouge", "Ballon vert"]

for j in ballon:
    nb=np.where(data['Unnamed: 1']==j)[0]
    totalballon.append(np.sum(data['Unnamed: 0'][nb]))
totalballon=[sum(totalballon)]
print(totalballon)

with pd.ExcelWriter('site.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    writer.book = load_workbook('site.xlsx')


    TOTALespece = np.sum(data['Unnamed: 3'][espece])
    TOTALcarte = np.sum(data['Unnamed: 3'][carte])
    TOTALcheque = np.sum(data['Unnamed: 3'][cheque])

    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'articles':articles})
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'nombres':b})
    df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Total ballon':totalballon})

    dfe = pd.DataFrame({'TOTAL Espèces':[TOTALespece]})
    dfcarte = pd.DataFrame({'TOTAL CB':[TOTALcarte]})
    dfcheque = pd.DataFrame({'TOTAL Chèque':[TOTALcheque]})

    df1.to_excel(writer, "Feuille2", index=False)
    df2.to_excel(writer, "Feuille2", index=False, startcol=1)
    df3.to_excel(writer, "Feuille2", index=False, startcol=2)
    dfe.to_excel(writer, "Feuille2", index=False, startcol=3)
    dfcarte.to_excel(writer, "Feuille2", index=False, startcol=4)
    dfcheque.to_excel(writer, "Feuille2", index=False, startcol=5)
    writer.book.save('site.xlsx')
    writer.book.close()
```

[Print(data) first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PYVo.png)

[Print(data) second time after launching the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XH1F.png)

The unamed column 3 is no longer displayed. It is in this column where there are all the excel formulas.
[My github with the excel file and the python code](https://github.com/Suntoryy/Help)

Comment: It has to do with the limitations of `xlsxwriter` and working with formulas. `"XlsxWriter doesn’t calculate the result of a formula and instead stores the value 0 as the formula result. It then sets a global flag in the XLSX file to say that all formulas and functions should be recalculated when the file is opened."` Check out the [documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html). Formulas are only interpreted  after the file is saved and then  reopened. That is why it works after saving the file opening it and re-running the code.

Comment: Yes, I see, but he doesn't give me a solution to my problem. So I have no choice. Do I have to record every time? there's no other way to do it. ?